# Use user/register instead of default login page for anonymous users

Tags: 7, users

This sounds simple enough but I can't make it work.

Only registered users can view the site content, but instead of the login block, I want users to go to the user/register page (with the 'login' and 'request new password' tabs also there), and after registering then be taken to the frontpage.

I've tried the [login redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_redirect) and [login destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) modules, but they don't help setting user/register as the defult page for anonymous users. I tried setting 'user/register' as the homepage in config/system/site-information and force logged-in users to the actual frontpage, but not surprisingly that didn't work. I tried disabling 'view published content' permission for anonymous users, and then set the 403 page to user/register, but nothing. I tried creating a rule (first time using [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)) as follows:

Event: drupal is initializing

Condition: user has anonymous role

Page redirect: user/register

And other variations I could think of, but to no avail.

I don't think it's that difficult and I'm probably missing something. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. In case someone looks for something similar, to the rule above I added another condition:

```
NOT Text comparison - Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: user
```